# Nesting loops - passing index

Tags: animation-nodes, looping

another misunderstanding I'm encountering is this - I'm trying to pass a list of the index inside a loop into another loop so I can travel through a long list - I've made a small demo of the problem I'm encountering as the actual file is a proper vipers nest of nodes.

[image]

I've attached an image and uploaded a file here

[blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49266)

Comment: ps this tutorial seems to make it work, but it didn't when I followed it... [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BcaQXkfeWs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, **Loop viewer** can display only one loop, not both. It clears every time, than loop 1 takes new value.

If you want to see result of Loop 1, pass value to output of loop 2.

[image]